# Why linker searches for a library in the path used for compiling in linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, linker, dlopen

I am building a shared library with option 
    " -L/my/path/ -lxxx.so "

Now i am using dlopen to dynamically link this library to my application

```
pvHandle = dlopen (pszLibName, RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_GLOBAL);
```

But when i execute it is showing an error message 
     /my/path/libxxx.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

libxxx.so is available in /usr/local/lib and i am appending this path to LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Any idea what i am doing wrong?
Thanks in advance

Comment: run `ldconfig ` command and try again.Also post output of `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `ldconfig` command. Also see man page of `ldconfig` command you can get idea about it.

you need to add the path to the file `/etc/ld.so.conf`.

OR

give full path like

```
dlopen("/some/path/to/lib.so",  RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_GLOBAL);
```